# How to use memory caching in Asp.Net core 2 without constructor

Tags: caching, constructor

In Asp.Net application(Class library project) , caching with `using System.Runtime`.Caching was working fine without use constructor.

```
protected ObjectCache ResponseCache
    {
        get
        {
            return MemoryCache.Default;
        }
    }
```

Now, I want to use same as in Asp.Net CORE application without constructor.
As Asp.Net CORE 2 is not supporting namespace `System.Runtime.Caching` and replace it `Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory`

I use this MemoryCache memoryCache = new MemoryCache(new MemoryCacheOptions()) but it create always new object which clear all old cache memories.

Note: I'm looking solution for without defined constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement it in ASP.NET Core way. That is, using dependency injection. You have to register the MemoryCache in the ConfigureServices method in the Startup class as:

```
services.AddMemoryCache();
```

then you need to inject the IMemoryClass in your controller to access it. You can check the docs for more details: [Cache in-memory in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/memory?view=aspnetcore-2.1)

That way, you will not be worrying much on passing dependencies to the constructor since the DI container will handle it automatically.

Comment: This is the part where I really struggle with DI as I'm learning it. Why should the controller have to deal with brokering an `IMemoryCache` reference which it need know nothing about and should actually never directly access itself? Doesn't this open it up for abuse of the dependencies by being used outside of their intended scopes?